# How to draw a matrix on winform

Tags: c#

I have an empty class Box that i make a matrix of like you se below and i want to draw this matrix on winform how can i do that ?

For example if `Box[i,j]` have red color and i change the color of the box like this`Box[i.j].color = Color.Black` så should my winform change the color of `Box[i,j]` to black after it draw the whole matrix.

```
   Box[,] boxes = new Box[100, 100];
    MainForm form;
    Timer timer;

    public Game()
    {
        form = new MainForm();
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void Run(int size)
    {
        form.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Draw);

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventHandler);
        timer.Interval = 1000 / 25;
        timer.Start();

        form.Visible = true;

    }

    private void TimerEventHandler(Object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        form.Refresh();
    }

    private void Draw(Object obj, PaintEventArgs args)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Please get a book or follow a tutorial. WinForm graphics is simply too complicated to guess your way through it, or even to give a simple answer to how to write an application. I know this is not what you want to hear, but it is the truth.

Comment: i understand what you mean but i search for a tutorial and looked for examples but didn’t find any thing that even close to what i want that’s why i asked here

Comment: You could create a matrix of panels and set the color of each of them. It's not the most efficient way, but it's simple to write.
Otherwise, you could draw to an off-screen bitmap, and display it in a PictureBox control (or similar).
The most efficient way would be to draw to a canvass.

Comment: What is your Box class? What can it do? Can it draw itself?

Comment: If you can't find a book or tutorial on this topic you seriously need to improve your research skills before you attempt any programming. Simply typing your title into Google showed many promising sites. If you are absolutely stuck, start at [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/write-your-first-windows10-app/).

Comment: my Box is only an empty box (empty class) that contains other classes so it’s a container for other objects. so for example if i make a snake game i can make to contain the object food. and because i have a matrix i can make the food spawn at random locations in the matrix this is an example of how box should work but Box can be replaced the important part here is how to draw this matrix on the winform

Comment: Actually, using a separate control (my previous comment) for that many items would give terrible performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach to doing it (not the only way):

First, give `Box` a method to draw itself to a Graphics context:

```
class Box
{
    public Color color { get; set; } = Color.Red;
    // Note: Conventionally, property names begin with a capital letter.

    /// <summary>
    /// Draw this block to the given graphics context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics context to draw to.</param>
    /// <param name="x">X-coordinate of the block within the graphics context.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Y-coordinate of the block within the graphics context.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of the area in which to draw the block.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Height of the area in which to draw the block.</param>
    public void DrawTo(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        // Fill in the color of this block:
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(color);     // fill style, color etc.
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, width, height);

        // Black outline:
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);       // line style, color, etc.
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);

        // look up the documentation of the System.Drawing.Graphics class for other methods for drawing.
    }
}
```

Now, if you wanted to draw the matrix to a bitmap image, you could do this:

```
    private void DrawMatrix(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        try
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < MatrixHeight; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < MatrixWidth; x++)
                {
                    boxes[x, y].DrawTo(g, x * CellWidth, y * CellHeight, CellWidth, CellHeight);
                }
        }
        finally
        {
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // Size of the matrix:
    const int MatrixWidth = 100;
    const int MatrixHeight = 100;

    // Size of each cell in pixels:
    const int CellWidth = 20;
    const int CellHeight = 20;
```

But that would be too slow to do each frame (for a 100x100 matrix).
You could update an off-screen image like this if you were updating only individual cells whenever they changed.

You could then place a `PictureBox` control on the form, and set its `Image` property to the Bitmap updated here. You can create that bitmap (parameter to this method) with `new Bitmap(MatrixWidth * CellWidth, MatrixHeight * CellHeight)` .

Alternatively, you could draw to the form's canvass in the OnPaint event handler (the `Draw` method in your question).
Assuming that the window scrolls (and not all of the matrix is visible within the viewport at any time),
you would loop through only the visible cells and make them draw themselves to the form's Graphics context.

The form's Graphics context is the property `Graphics` on the event arguments object. This is what you need for the `Box.Draw` method above. When drawing each cell, you have to take account of its position in the grid and how the window is scrolled, in order to calculate the coordinates to be passed to that method.

On each invocation of the OnPaint event, only part of the window has to be redrawn. This part is given by the property `ClipRectangle` . (Windows breaks down the area to be redrawn into one or more rectangles, and does a call for each rectangle.)
(`ClipRectangle` could be the whole window.)
Drawing outside of this is allowed but can be inefficient.

So, for efficiency, you should loop through only all cells that fall at least partly within `ClipRectangle`, calculate their position within the visible area and call their `Box.Draw`.

The coordinates used with the `Graphics` class are the visible coordinates, so (0,0) is the top left of the window, regardless of scrolling.

See these properties for the scroll position:

```
Form.HorizontalScroll.Value
Form.VerticalScroll.Value
```